# iPhone development on a jailbroken phone

Tags: iphone

I have a jailbroken phone which for whatever reason will not work when I try to restore the original software. So I'm stuck on the jailbroken version.

Will there be any problems in joining the Apple developer program, getting my app loaded onto my phone for testing, and then getting my app into the app store?

Answer (score 2):

no, don't worry. When you will pay for iPhone Developer Program Apple just give you certificate to sign your applications for testing on your phone